# VisualForce page not showing up in the "Content" picklist for detail page link

Tags: visualforce

I want the following visualforce page to pop up when I click on a custom link from the opporunity page with the record information. But I am not able to select this visualforce page since this visualforce page is not showing up in the content picklist of the custom link set up page.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" recordSetVar="opportunities" >
    <apex:form >
          <apex:inputText value="{!opportunity.stageName}"/>
         <apex:inputText value="{!opportunity.closeDate}"/>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not showing up becos you have `recordSetVar="opportunities"` in your `apex:page`.

this will make the page available only for list views and other places where you can operate on multiple records..

if you update your page by removing the recordSetVar, then your page should become available in the Content dropdown.

I just tested in my dev org and it works.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" >
    <apex:form >
          <apex:inputText value="{!opportunity.stageName}"/>
         <apex:inputText value="{!opportunity.closeDate}"/>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```